# Eleventy addPassthroughCopy for Javascript folder doesn't copy files

Tags: javascript, module, nunjucks, eleventy

Probably I'm missing something completely obvious. I tried to pass through my main.js file but nothing seems to work.

```
module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("./src/assets/js");
    eleventyConfig.addWatchTarget("./src/assets/");
  
    return {
      dir: {
        input: "src",
        output: "public",
      },
    };
  };
```

My folder structure is set up as follows

```
eleventy-project
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ _includes
 ┃ ┃ ┗ base.njk
 ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┗ js
 ┃ ┃   ┗ main.js
 ┃ ┗ index.njk
 ┣ .eleventy.js
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┗ package.json
```

Everything else works. The target watch works, input and output directories work but the passthroughCopy doesn't do anything.

Does anybody see my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, stupid me. The passthrough seems only to take effect on build not on serve (at least in 11ty 2.0). Site works, it just copies the files only on build.